# Nested call of consteval functions with a reference argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, consteval

The following program

```
template<class T>
consteval auto foo(const T&) {
   return 0;
}

template<class T>
consteval auto bar(const T& t) {
   auto n = foo(t);
   return n;
}

int main() {
   static_assert(foo("abc") == 0);
   static_assert(bar("abc") == 0);
}
```

is built fine in GCC, but Clang rejects it with the messages:

```
error: call to consteval function 'foo<char[4]>' is not a constant expression
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'bar<char[4]>' requested here
   static_assert(bar("abc") == 0);
note: function parameter 't' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression
   auto n = foo(t);
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M6GPnYdqb

Is it some bug in Clang?

Comment: Note: this compiler variance does not only show up for reference arguments, but also for pointers.

Comment: Surprise, I change `consteval auto bar(const T& t)` into `consteval auto bar(T t)` then it compiles for clang. Hope someone can have this clarified.

Comment: @SHP, this might be related: [Why is a `constexpr` function on a reference not `constexpr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124899/why-is-a-constexpr-function-on-a-reference-not-constexpr)

Comment: @Evg: Notice that replacing `consteval` by `constexpr` works [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7vn17ndWo).

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166564 However, this question is better phrased (clearer title, and clearer code snippet). Also, the answer on that duplicate is not particularly useful, so I'm going to go ahead and use this question as a target once (if) it's answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a clang bug. gcc and msvc are correct to accept it.

There are two relevant rules in question:

All *immediate invocations* must be constant expressions. This comes from [[expr.const]/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#13):

> An expression or conversion is in an *immediate function context* if it is potentially evaluated and either:
>
> - its innermost enclosing non-block scope is a function parameter scope of an immediate function, or
> - its enclosing statement is enclosed ([stmt.pre]) by the compound-statement of a consteval if statement ([stmt.if]).
>
> An expression or conversion is an *immediate invocation* if it is a potentially-evaluated explicit or implicit invocation of an immediate function and is not in an immediate function context. An immediate invocation shall be a constant expression.

And touching an unknown reference is not allowed in constant expressions (this is [[expr.const]/5.13](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.13)):

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following: [...]
>
> - an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is usable in constant expressions or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of E;

For more on this latter rule, see my post on the [the constexpr array size problem](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/) and [my proposal to resolve this](https://wg21.link/p2280) (hopefully for C++23).

---

Okay, back to the problem. `foo` is obviously fine, it doesn't do anything.

In `bar`, we call `foo(t)`. This is not a constant expression (because `t` is an unknown reference), but we are in an immediate function context (because `bar` is `consteval`), so it doesn't matter that `foo(t)` is not a constant expression. All that matters is that `bar("abc")` is a constant expression (since that *is* an immediate invocation), and there's no rule we're violating there. It is pretty subtle, but the reference `t` here *does* have its lifetime begin within the evaluation of `E` -- since `E` here is the call `bar("abc")`, *not* the call `foo(t)`.

If you mark `bar` `constexpr` instead of `consteval`, then the `foo(t)` call inside of it becomes an immediate invocation, and now the fact that it is not a constant expression is relevant. All three compilers correctly reject in this case.